# Disable opening documents in office by default

Tags: office-integration, word, office

Is it possible to turn off completely opening word and excel documents in office? What I want is when user clicks an word document is library, sharepoint will not open it office but standard download window of browser will be displayed, and user can save file on his hard drive.

We have claims based application with sharepoint learning kit and we can't get assignments which are office documents open properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This involves disabling client integration. Here are a couple resources.

- [Set the "Enable Client Integration" Setting](http://njbblog.blogspot.com/2011/09/sharepoint-40-how-to-set-enable-client.html)
- [Sharepoint and Office Integration](http://www.grayston.net/2010/sharepoint-and-office-integration-lets-remove-it/)

Comment: It works for regular libraries, but unfortunately when trying to get sharepoint learning kit assignment which is a word document (clicking link which points to absolute document path in DropBox library), following error occurs:
`The document could not be opened for editing. A Microsoft SharePoint Foundation compatible application could not be found to edit the document.`